# Angular JS with ngMock & Jasmine causing Promise issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, location-services, angularjs-ngmock

I am new to Jasmine JS & ngMock.

When I am trying to inject ngMock in angular & accessing `$location` service for injecting in controller for Testing purpose.

I am not getting promise response. Please help me.

I am getting below error

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: code .. show us the code ........

Comment: did you get the answer to your problem?